# Return "True" if all the characters in a string are "x" or "X" else return false

Tags: javascript

I am looking at this code challenge:

> Complete the function isAllX to determine if the entire string is made of lower-case x or upper-case X. Return true if they are, false if not.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> isAllX("Xx"); // true
> isAllX("xAbX"); // false
> ```

Below is my answer, but it is wrong. I want "false" for the complete string if any of the character is not "x" or "X":

```js
function isAllX(string) {
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (string[i] === "x" || string[i] === "X") {
      console.log(true);
    } else if (string[i] !== "x" || string[i] !== "X") {
      console.log(false);
    }
  }
}

isAllX("xAbX");
```

Comment: `string.toLowerCase() === 'x'.repeat(string.length)`. See [`String.prototype.repeat()` - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any method if you want

```
 function isAllX(str) {
  let flag = true;
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] !== "x" && str[i] !== "X") {
      flag = false;
      // break;
    }
  }
  return flag;
}

console.log(isAllX("xAbX"));
console.log(isAllX("XXXxxxXXXxxx"));
console.log(isAllX("xx"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Your loop is outputting a result *in every* iteration. There are two issues with that:

1. You should only give *one* result for an input, so not in every iteration; currently you are reporting on every single character in the input string.
2. You are asked to *return* a boolean result (false/true), not to have the function *print* something. That should be left to the caller

You could take a simpler approach though, and first turn the input string to all lower case. Now you only have to look for "x". Then take out all "x" and see if something is left over. You can check the `length` property of the resulting string to decide whether the return value should be false or true:

```js
function isAllX(string) {
  return string.toLowerCase().replaceAll("x", "").length == 0;
}


console.log(isAllX("xxXXxxAxx")); // false
console.log(isAllX("xxXXxxXxx")); // true
```

If you are confortable with regular expressions, you could also use the `test` method:

```js
function isAllX(string) {
  return /^x*$/i.test(string);
}


console.log(isAllX("xxXXxxAxx")); // false
console.log(isAllX("xxXXxxXxx")); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way.

```js
function isAllX(str) {
    let isX = true;
    let newString = str.toLowerCase();

    for (let i = 0; i < newString.length; i++) {
        if (newString[i] !== "x") {
            isX = false;
        }
    }
    return isX;
}
console.log(isAllX("xAbX"));
console.log(isAllX("XXXxxxXXXxxx"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to find the same.

```js
function allX(testString) {
  return /^x+$/i.test(testString);
}

console.log(allX("xxXX"));
console.log(allX("xxAAAXX"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try converting the string to a single case, then looping over it while checking for the condition as below

```js
function isAllX(string) {
    const newString = string.toUpperCase();
    for (let i = 0; i < newString.length; i++) {
    if (newString[i] !== "X") {
      return false
    }
    }return true
}
```